What is the origin of this underwater low-frequency upsweep signal?
I've been trying to identify underwater sounds recorded in the eastern North Atlantic Ocean, at a 500 Hz sampling rate. I observed this low-frequency upsweep that was only produced once, but it shows high SNR and it is well-defined. However, I'm not sure if this is from a humpback whale (my first guess), because of the low frequency and only being produced once and by itself (no aliased parts of a song). Does anyone know what animal produces this type of sound? All the help is much appreciated! The first image is a close-up of the signal, and the second is one hour of recording around it.



I am no expert on this domain, but 20 seconds seems VERY long for an animal-produced upsweep, doesn't it? So I'd be inclined to think this may come from some mechanical source. But in either case, it's strange to see such a clear strong signal with apparently nothing else before/after.

I'm not sure what these are, but wondering if there are some tonal signals around 50 and 20 Hz in the longer duration sample that might be a clue?

Thank you for your comments @DanStowell and @BrianMiller! Yes, the signal seems to be too long for a biological source, but it has such clear characteristics and high SNR... I guess it will remain a mystery for now... Before the upsweep, the  tonal noise at 50 Hz seems to be shipping noise maybe? And after the upsweep,  the low-frequency noise at 20 Hz might be instrumental. Doesn't seem to be fin whale signals...
